# Why cant i use serveo instead of ngrok to tunnel connection to a mvc application hosted on EC2 server for receiving SMS on Twilio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, ngrok

I have a simple asp.net mvc web application which listens for a message and replied back with a standard response. It uses the Twilio API and in

Here is the code:

```
// Code sample for ASP.NET MVC on .NET Framework 4.6.1+
// In Package Manager, run:
// Install-Package Twilio.AspNet.Mvc -DependencyVersion HighestMinor

using Twilio.AspNet.Common;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class SmsController : TwilioController
    {
        public TwiMLResult Index(SmsRequest incomingMessage)
        {
            var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
            messagingResponse.Message("The copy cat says: " +
                                      incomingMessage.Body);

            return TwiML(messagingResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

For the code to run, Twilio suggests me **"While there are a lot of ways to do this, like deploying your application to Azure or AWS, you'll probably want a less laborious way to test your Twilio like ngrok to allow Twilio to Talk to Your ASP.NET Application"**

I have used ngrok, which allows me to expose my local environment to the whole public internet which can then be accessed by URL provided by ngrok,
but the free version keeps changing the subdomain whenever I restart my ec2 server (thus restarting the ngrok tunnel).

What I would like to know is I tried an alternate called serveo which allowed me to chose a subdomain for free,  but the URL generated it given an error (400) when I send a message to Twilio.

Is there a way around? I m new to the world of asp.net mcv web application and Twilio and would really appreciate some guidance.

I just need this code to keep running so that it can listen for SMS and respond back.

If not, How can I deploy it on AWS? Which would provide me with an URL to feed to the Twilio's console

Comment: Are you looking for a way to deploy your code so that it can continue to run or are you still testing?

Comment: @philnash I am looking for a way to deploy it.

Comment: In that case I’d look into finding some tutorials for deploying asp.net applications on AWS or Azure. Using ngrok (or any tunnelling solution) is for testing your local app.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 'serveo' isn't working is because (I believe) you are using IIS Express which doesn't allow requests with host header's other than localhost.

'ngrok' has a way around that, as does our free VS Extension called Conveyor.  Conveyor at the moment has tunnelling in beta, but it is stable and subdomains are fixed.  You can download it from the Extensions menu in VS or marketplace.  Here's a tutorial for Twilio https://conveyor.cloud/Help/Writing_webhooks_on_localhost_with_Visual_Studio_and_IIS_Express